# Possible to insert arguments into an array?

Tags: c

My question is simple: If I have an input of ./foo 3 6 9
the output should be: 
average : 6
min value: 3
max value: 9

now the question lies. Is it possible to store the command line arguments into an array? 
I was thinking something like:

```
int numbers[50];
int i = 0; 
int j = 1;

while(argv[j]!=null) {
  numbers[i] = atoi(argv[j]); 
  i++;
  j++; 
}
```

Comment: Does your code work? What happens? What do you need help with?

Comment: nicomp - I inserted a print statement (printing the array) at the end of the while loop to see if it does actually work. Yet, it doesn't seem to.

Comment: Actually, it did work, I had it as argv[ i ]; for some reason in my program.... smh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible to store the command line arguments in an array. You can do something like the following to store the arguments after argv[0]:

```
int numbers[50];
int i = 0;

while(i+1 < argc) {
    numbers[i] = atoi(argv[i+1]); 
    printf(" %d ", numbers[i]); 

    i++;
}
```

You should use `argc` as it indicates the number of arguments that were used in the invocation of the program.

Please note that this is only an example and I'm not considering any validations on the input.